# Way to Check Conditions in a Constructor

Tags: methods, constructor, initialization

This is the code i have written :

```
class Car
public Car(String Company,String Model,int Color,String FuelType,double Price,String Engine)
{
boolean  check =  ConstInitCheck(Company,FuelType,Engine,Color);
if((check))
{
this.Company = Company;
this.Model = Model;
this.Color = Color;
this.FuelType = FuelType;
this.Price = Price;
this.Engine = Engine;
}
else System.out.println("Sorry One of the Inputs were wrong! Please Try Again!");
}


public Car(String Company,String Model,int Color,String FuelType,double Price,String Engine,String VIP_Features)
{
boolean  check =  ConstInitCheck(Company,FuelType,Engine,Color);
if((check))
{
this.Company = Company;
this.Model = Model;
this.Color = Color;
this.FuelType = FuelType;
this.Price = Price;
this.Engine = Engine;
if(!VIP_Features.equals(""))this.VIP_Features = VIP_Features;
else this.VIP_Features="None";
}
else System.out.println("Sorry One of the Inputs were wrong! Please Try Again!");
}



private boolean ConstInitCheck(String Company,String FuelType,String Engine,int Color)
{
boolean a = ((Company.toUpperCase().equals("SUZUKI"))||(Company.toUpperCase().equals("TOYOTA"))||(Company.toUpperCase().equals("HYUNDAI"))||
(Company.toUpperCase().equals("VOLKSWAGEN"))||(Company.toUpperCase().equals("FORD"))||(Company.toUpperCase().equals("HONDA"))||(Company.toUpperCase().equals
("CHEVROLET"))||(Company.toUpperCase().equals("SKODA"))||(Company.toUpperCase().equals("FIAT")));
boolean b = ((FuelType.toUpperCase().equals("DIESEL"))||(FuelType.toUpperCase().equals("PETROL"))||(FuelType.toUpperCase().equals("GAS")));
boolean c = ((Engine.toUpperCase().equals("V2"))||(Engine.toUpperCase().equals("V4"))||(Engine.toUpperCase().equals("V6"))||(Engine.toUpperCase().equals("V8"))||

(Engine.toUpperCase().equals("V12")));
boolean d = Color >= 0 & Color <= 255;
boolean initcheck = a && b && c && d;
return initcheck;
}
```

Some posts I read here , are against executing methods inside a constructor since the object is not initialized Completely.
but since the method i am calling only checks if the actual parameters entered are correct or not
is it the right way?
if not please suggest me the best way to do so.
Suggestion or Criticism on other aspects of code are also welcome.

Comment: Throw an exception instead of/in addition to using `System.out.println`. You don't want the calling code to attempt to use the object if it's not correctly constructed, which can easily happen here.

Comment: Additionally, what does `ConstInitCheck` do? You're not passing any parameters to it, what is it checking?

Comment: I saw that, and edited the code

Comment: Ok, but can you please go over the code and edit it *completely*? It wastes everyones time if you ask "Can my code be improved" and then you edit the code as you go along. Yes it can be improved, why don't *you* improve it first, *then* ask us what else can be done? (also, note that you have two calls to ConstInitCheck)

Comment: ya sorry for that. actually that was already there in my code but while creating the post I might have accidentally deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory method. Moving the checks to a method and outside the constructor.
Result is a valid object or no object at all.

```
    class Car{

       //private constructor to prevent creating objects from outside the factory method
       private Car(String Company,String Model,int Color,String FuelType,double Price,String Engine,String VIP_Features)
       {
          this.Company = Company;
          this.Model = Model;
          this.Color = Color;
          this.FuelType = FuelType;
          this.Price = Price;
          this.Engine = Engine;
       }

       //static method that creates the object after functional checks
       public static Car Create(String Company,String Model,int Color,String FuelType,double Price,String Engine,String VIP_Features)
       {
          if(ConstInitCheck(Company,FuelType,Engine,color)){
              return new Car(Company,Model,Color,FuelType,Price,Engine,VIP_Features);
          }
          return null; // or throw exception
       }

       private static boolean ConstInitCheck(String Company,String FuelType,String Engine,int Color){
          ...
       }

    }
```

Usage:

```
var car = Car.Create(Company,Model,Color,FuelType,Price,Engine,VIP_Features);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am new to Java that's why had no idea how Design Patters work.Ill Look into it and try it out.